# What can you do with lambda calculus if you aren't allowed parentheses?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Is there a concise/existing way to denote the expressive power of "lambda calc without using parentheses/tree-of-expressions/application-order-restructuring anywhere"?

Can you do without them/reinvent them? Does it break completely (i.e, even with a naive no-more-parentheses, you're using them implicitly, like when naming things)? Does it become completely trivial/boring?

I haven't tried very hard, but I feel like I couldn't express something like

$\lambda x y z . x y (x z)$

without using parentheses somewhere.

Comment: Are we allowed to write $\lambda xyz.xyz$ even if $xyz$ is $((xy)z)$ ? what about $(\lambda x. x(\lambda y. y))$ ? I can't understand exactly what would you allow.

Comment: Yes, you couldn't. What would you replace parenthesis with? The lack of parenthesis in some lambda expressions are based on some conventions (like precedence or associativity). Strictly speaking -i.e. if you forget about conventions-, every lambda expression has parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

#### Answer 1

The best answer to this question is: This is the **wrong** question to ask! Let me explain.

The fact that we write down expressions (in $\lambda$-calculus or anywhere else) as sequences of symbols is a *convenience* and *tradition* established by humans. From a theoretical point of view the strings of symbols are not the optimal way of representing expressions. Instead, [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) are.

Abstract syntax trees do not require any parentheses. Parentheses are there *only* because we use a particular way of writing things. There is nothing deep in having or not having parenthesis. Your question then boils down to the following: "Suppose we use a notation which requires parentheses, but then we remove parenthesis, what happens?" This is not a mathematically interesting question. It *can* be answered, but it's *irrelevant* for $\lambda$-calculus. The answer might be interesting, but it will not reveal anything about parentheses. Instead, it will reveal something about abstract syntax trees of a certain shape.

Were you born in a slightly different universe, where everyone used [reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) then you would not have known that there is such a thing as parentheses.

Let me put it another way. It is a *convention* that in $\lambda$-calculus we write $a\,b\,c$ to mean $(a\,b)\,c$. Without such a convention we would always have to write parentheses everywhere, all the time. The first person to establish the convention could have picked the other one, so that $a\,b\,c$ would mean $a\,(b\,c)$. Then your question would have a different answer because of some person who picked a convention a long time ago.

#### Answer 2

It is not entirely clear where you *think* parentheses are needed, but let's suppose that

1. application is left-associative, so that $x y z = (x y) z$, and
2. $\lambda$-abstraction has lower precedence than application, and it binds as much as it can, so that $\lambda x . x y z$ and $(\lambda x . x y) z$ are different expressions.
3. You think that $x \lambda y . y$ is not a valid expression because it should be written as $x (\lambda y . y)$. That is, a $\lambda$-abstraction in an aplication must always be parenthesized.

Under these conditions, we cannot ever write any $\beta$-redeces (because we would have to apply a $\lambda$-abstraction). So any expression must be of the form $\lambda x_1 . \lambda x_2 . \ldots \lambda x_n . M$, possibly with $n = 0$, where $M$ is of the form $y_1 y_2 \ldots y_m$ for some variables $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ (which may be equal to the $x_i$'s).

If anyone can say anything interesting about this fragment of $\lambda$-calculus, I'd be interested to hear.